# Are "a dog big eyed" and "big eyed dog" valid constructions in English?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

1. a dog big eyed
2. big eyed dog

First: I would like to ask if 1 and 2 are the same in meaning?

Second: are they valid constructions?

and finally: is "eyed" an adjective?

Comment: 1. No. 2. Yes. 3. Yes.

Comment: Can you provide a longer sentence in which you would use these expressions? I don't find (1) very natural.  _Big-eyed_ could be written with a hyphen, like _black-haired_ and _long-legged_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I would like to know which if any situation I can place the big eyed in front of dog(the noun), get it?

Comment: @Kate Bunting, also I would like to know if big eyed is exactly the same as "big eye" right? I mean: the "big eye dog" is same as "the big eyed dog" correct?

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I believe when we put the "big eyed" after dog is same as when we put Impossible after Mission as in Mission Impossible correct?

Comment: It appears that the TV series was actually called _Mission: Impossible_ with a colon between the words.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, so there is no situation that satisfies an adjective goes after the noun?

Comment: Only in certain set phrases, as I mention in my answer. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective#Set_phrases).

Answer (score 2):

"eyed" means "having eyes of the type or number specified". It's an adjective. You can make compound adjective with it:

> a one-eyed monster

> a blue-eyed girl

You can say

> A dog big-eyed me.

meaning the dog attentively looked at you with their big eyes.

> I saw a big-eyed dog.

meaning you met a dog who had big eyes.

Answer (score 2):

An expression like *big-eyed* normally comes before the thing that it describes. It can't be replaced with *big eye dog.*

We don't normally put the adjective after the noun in English, except in some special cases like *court martial*. In literary language we might follow a noun with a phrase describing it, for example:

> A dog, big-eyed and long-haired, came towards us wagging its tail.

Comment: get it. But what would be the difference between: "big eyed dog" and "big eye dog"??

Comment: Americans say 'I ate a big-ass burger', don't they?

Comment: @Michael Harvey, I guess they do LOL!, and that makes "big eyed dog" and "big eye dog" the same?

Comment: @thralhothakles - I'm not sure if the 'big-ass' relates to the burger or the effect on the eater. Being serious, using an adjective phrase like this: 'a big-eye dog' is non-standard, casual, informal and regional.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, hmm interesting, would you be able of develop an example on how "big-ass" would have any effect on the eater?

Comment: Michael is joking that eating a big burger would make you put on weight and have a big bottom!